# How to send data filled in from an Adaptive Card back to TestFlow and TestAdapter for testing?

Tags: c#, testing, botframework

There are some testing tools available on the Enterprise Bot Template with TestFlow and Adapter.

Can we use TestFlow to submit test data as if it was filled and submitted in an Adaptive Card back to the bot to test the response from a TestMethod? Instead of a text, a filled out response back.

[image]

The method is below, with comments placed where the appropriate actions should be.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestSoftwareIssue()
{
    string response = "What sort of issue do you have?\n\n" +
                    "   1. Computer\n" +
                    "   2. Software\n" +
                    "   3. Insuffient Permissions for Access\n" +
                    "   4. Account expired\n" +
                    "   5. Other";
    await GetTestFlow()
        .Send(GeneralUtterances.GeneralIssue)
        .AssertReply(response)
        .Send("software")
        // .AssertReply("")
        .AssertReply(activity => CheckAttachment(activity.AsMessageActivity()))
        // How to send a Adaptive Card filled out message back?
        .StartTestAsync();
}
```

Here is also, a simplified version of the Adaptive Card.

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Email"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "id": "Email",
            "placeholder": "name@example.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Summary"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "id": "Summary",
            "placeholder": "Please describe the issue",
            "isMultiline": true
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit",
            "data": {
                "form": "Ticket"
            }
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Can we see the Adaptive Card? I'm particularly interested in the submit action so I can see if it's an imBack or a postBack

Comment: @KyleDelaney Hi, I've attached a simplified version of the Adaptive Card in the original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update.
I've managed to get a working implementation like this.

Here's an example test where responseOne is a string formatted in json that holds key value pairs for the data fields in accessForm.json

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestFormProcess()
// ...
await GetTestFlow()
    .Send(GeneralUtterances.Access)
    .AssertReply(activity => CheckAttachment(activity.AsMessageActivity(), @".\Resources\TestForms\accessForm.json"))
    .Send(CreateReply(responseOne))
    .AssertReply("Some reply")
    .StartTestAsync();
```

```
public IActivity CreateReply(string json)
        {
            return new Activity()
            {
                Value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(file),
            };
        }
```

Comment: If this is working, would you like to mark this answer as correct?